# Facebook Graph API: (#200) Permissions error

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Using `/{event-id}/attending` method call from iOS. I worked for long time, and nowadays Get no result, and this message. Do you know why? What changed?

In iOS app, list of user is just empty.
In `Graph API Explorer` some error I get. I do not know why two results are different? And we it just not works as before?

[image]

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong - possible due to recent Facebook security issues ?

Comment: I have no clue.

Comment: If possible, post it on Facebook developer forum.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/192446981367570/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That endpoint is deprecated now:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Deprecated: Endpoints that return data including /feed, /posts, /comments, and the RSVP list.

Comment: How long it will take to get app approved again? How this approval will look like, like in App Store?

Comment: that endpoint is deprecated and gone, there is nothing to get approved, i am afraid.

Comment: But if FB remove the `attending`, `interested` edge, then for what `Events` are good for? An event without member info?

Comment: You can still get basic Event data, but that is all. It may be possibe that they remove the whole Events API. Either way, getting user data was the big issue, you should not get user data without explicit permission of users, that is why those endpoints are gone.

Comment: Do you think it is possible get member data without API? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706210/get-facebook-data-without-graph-api

Comment: Maybe you have idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714149/integrate-wkwebview-and-facebook-graph-api

Comment: "All apps, including formerly approved apps, must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the API." -> Where you can request a review: "We are not reviewing apps at this time due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform." #awesome #welldonefacebook

Comment: facebook? better say thanx to cambridge analytica and other ones. they are to blame ;)