# Get Facebook data without Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook just closed API like Events because of Cambridge Analytica case. Do you think it is possible to get data parsing that certain event facebook website logged in as a normal user, and get needed data from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, scraping is not allowed on Facebook and never was. There is no way.

https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: ` Do you think it is possible to get data parsing that certain event facebook website logged in as a normal user, and get needed data from there?` - whether it's against the TOS or not isn't the question

Comment: actually, that´s the only relevant answer. if it´s not allowed, don´t do it. period. we are honest developers on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @Zoe granted, but since the actual question rather translates to "I know Facebook shut this down due to abusive $!%&heads, so what are my options now to continue being one?", I don't think it deserves an answer at all.

Comment: Maybe you have idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714149/integrate-wkwebview-and-facebook-graph-api

Comment: you really should not ask for help on another thread all the time, stay on topic. i would have seen it anyway ;)